# custom iso, error rebuilding initrd (mkinitramfs)

Tags: upgrade, kernel, iso

I'm creating a custom ISO (starting with ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso) and wanting to upgrade it's kernel to latest (for me that's 3.13.0-38-generic).  I'm following the instructions in [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Rebuilding_initrd).  I'm building a custom ISO for off-line installations.

I have an extracted ISO and chroot to the "[edit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Prepare_and_chroot)" jail and preform:

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
```

but when I try to rebuild inited

```
root@ff:/# mkinitramfs -o /initrd.gz
grep: /boot/config-3.13.0-38-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_9fqHlg/lib/modules/3.13.0-38-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_9fqHlg/lib/modules/3.13.0-38-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
```

so i grab a /boot/config from another device and try again:

```
root@ff:/# mkinitramfs -o /initrd.gz
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_CAG80R/lib/modules/3.13.0-38-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_CAG80R/lib/modules/3.13.0-38-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
```

my /lib/modules:

```
root@ff:/# ls /lib/modules/3.13.0-38-generic/
build          modules.alias.bin    modules.dep      modules.devname modules.symbols
modules.alias  modules.builtin.bin  modules.dep.bin  modules.softdep  modules.symbols.bin
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apt-get install linux-generic
```

Fixed my problem

Comment: Wow. I'm an idiot. I must have uninstalled this, and forgot to reinstall...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a kernel version, then it defaults to the version you are currently running.  Since your system has been updated since the iso was built, you are running a newer kernel version that is not present in the chroot, so it can't find it.  Take a look at what version is installed ( `ls /boot` ) and specify that like `mkinitramfs -o /initrd.gz 3.13.0-20`.